# Get number of complete minutes between two dates

Tags: ms-access, difference

I am using ms access to get the number of complete minutes between two dates. The function does not behave as expected.

For example, the following code:

```
DateDiff('n','9/24/2016 9:08:55 AM','9/24/2016 9:09:00 AM')
```

returns 1! Though the difference is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You have it correct, you simply need to swap `"n"` for `"s"`.

"n" = minute
"s" = second

So, `DateDiff("s",cdate("9/24/2016 9:08:55 AM"),cdate("9/24/2016 9:09:00 AM"))`

Then of course just divide by 60 (use `\` for whole minutes only, or `Round()` if you want to return 1 or 2 decimals of precision).

[See here for documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your single-quotes with double-quotes and *#* to obtain true date values:

```
MinuteDifference = DateDiff("n", #9/24/2016 9:08:55 AM#, #9/24/2016 9:09:00 AM#)
```

However, it will return the difference in displayed minutes: 9 - 8 = 1.

To return full minutes, you can use this (using *integer* division) to divide the difference in seconds by 60:

```
MinuteDifference = DateDiff("s", #9/24/2016 9:08:55 AM#, #9/24/2016 9:09:00 AM#) \ 60
```